# Gap in Waterfall Loadtime test

Tags: performance, http, wordpress, page-speed

When I test my wordpress websites with GTmetrix oder other Loadtime Testing tools I notice a gap in the Waterfall graph where no action is taking place. It looks like the time this gap is lost which leads to higher loading times. 
Is this the correct way of interpreting it? I even see it when testing some really large websites such as microsoft. Is this a server issue or normal? Can this gap be closed?

Please see the attached screenshot

[Speedtest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljlox.png)

Comment: Please include the full image, including the resource being loaded and the timeframe. It makes a difference to the answer. Initial thoughts are it could be asynchronous resources like Google Analytics or processing time while resources are parsed to determine what needs to be loaded next. webpagetest.org provides a graph of CPU usage during page load which could be of interest.

Comment: Thanks for the indication. Please have a look at this Report : https://gtmetrix.com/reports/xpuls.com/qy00lRpI

Comment: Here's another site on our server: https://www.webpagetest.org/result/170226_BE_27TJ/1/details/#waterfall_view_step1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the updated information, I can see that the client CPU is max'd out during page load. I suspect it's progressively parsing resources and building the page as resources and CPU allow.

Try using Chrome / Firefox developer [console network tab](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/resource-loading), watching your PC CPU. It may have more resources.

You could try putting directives in the page to preload resources you know are required, or using http/2 server push, though http/2 web server support is limited as it's relatively new.

I can't check for you as your website seems to be down.

Comment: interesting take on the issue. How can I check it locally ? So you say that enabling HTTP2 might fix the issue?

Comment: Like I said, the Firefox or Chrome developer console. They both give you a visual representation of page load time. Open task manager at the same time to track CPU. http/2 may help by pushing required resources, but web server support is just about non-existent for http/2 push. CloudFlare CDN supports http/2 and server push but I haven't managed to get it to work yet, but I only tried for 20 minutes.

Comment: Added a link. I tried it for you but your website seems to be down.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and for trying the site. We are having problems with the server right now so there might be some downtime. I tried testing it via Dev console but the output is quite confusing for me as I've never used it. I'll look into some tutorials

Comment: Here are the latest test results: https://www.webpagetest.org/result/170227_7H_1BSF/ I actually only want to know if there is anything abnormal about the waterfall chart or if these gaps are anything to be concerned about from a performance perspective. Is it a wordpress theme issue or a server issue or is it none of the above ? :-)

Comment: I wouldn't be concerned. Your website uses asynchronous loading of images so it could be that.

Comment: Tim I really appreciate your input!